# Platform services getting hang

Tags: endeca

We are using endeca 11.x and recently we did OS upgrade on endeca servers. Now we are facing Eac communication issue between ITL and CAS server. I restarted Platform Services on both and the job will run for 1hr and after that it is throwing EAC communication exception. Other than that there is no error log in any file. After going through catalina file I found that Platform Services will stop responding and give Socket Timeout exception after 1 hr.

Any pointer on what could be the issue or what should I check will be really helpful.

Thanks
Neha

Comment: Did you try cleaning up PlatformService's workspace state folder ? (1. Stop P/S 2. Rename existing "state" folder to some other name 3. Create an empty "state" folder 4. Restart P/S 5. Do a fresh initialize_services and retry).

Comment: If above didn't help, please post the full exception stack trace and P/S logs (logs/shell, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but I am getting multiple exception